# Notepad++ regular expression for moving a line with a duplicate to the end of the file

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm having trouble figuring out how to write a regular expression for editing a file I have.
It's a file of about 10,000 entries and some lines only have one word and then the next 1 to 10 lines start with that one word, and so I'm trying to use regex to find every line that has a line or more after it that starts with that initial word, and move them all to the end of the file or export them to another file.

So a sequence of entries might be:

```
1  
2  
3a  
3a eff  
3a jll  
4  
5  
5 eff  
5 yii
```

I am trying to have the "3a-3a jll" moved to the end of the file, and then have the regex identify and move "5-5 yii" to the end of the file and so on.

So the outcome would be:

```
1  
2  
4  
3a  
3a eff  
3a jll  
5  
5 eff  
5 yii
```

Comment: Oof. Man, I'm all for regular expressions, but they may just be the wrong tool for the job here.

Comment: I think if I spent all day scouring the file and copying and pasting, or bookmarking and then removing at once then I would end up with the answer I need. I just figured there was regex for "compare line to next line, if match, check next lines until there is no match, move all matching lines to end or beginning of file or export."

Comment: I'm pretty sure that requires context-awareness and possibly Turing-completeness, neither of which regex has.

Comment: Would you also want to treat `1<newline>12<newline>` as a "block" of lines to be moved? After all, both start with `1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving them to the end of the file within a regex operation will probably not be possible in one go, but if Notepad++ has an option to collect all regex matches in a new file, then you could do the following:

Search for

```
^(\w+)\s*?[\r\n]+(?:\1.*[\r\n]+)+
```

and collect all the matches in a new file.

Then run the same search again, but this time remove all the matches (replace them with the empty string).

Then concatenate your edited file and the file with the collected matches.

If you want to make sure that the "words" are only matched in their entirety (and not treat `foo<newline>foobar<newline>` as a "block"), add a `\b` after `\1`.

Comment: This is perfect! It selects the sections based on the first entry, that's exactly what I was looking for. Doing it by hand is much easier now, so this is perfect, thank you very much Tim.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thank you for welcoming me! Would you mind if I asked you for a followup for the regex you gave me? I want it to only select if when it compares the first word to the next it finds that the first word is followed by an underscore or dash in the next words. Possibly also, if it is possible, what would I change in the regex to have it not select that first word it is comparing the rest to. You've already given me enough to try to figure it out myself but I figure there's no harm asking.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the first requirement can be solved as `^(\w+)\s*?[\r\n]+(?:\1[_-].*[\r\n]+)+` (note the `[_-]` [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) after `\1`). The second requirement is trickier. Some regex engines could handle this (.NET, for example), but Notepad++'s can't, unfortunately. The space in the comments isn't enough for a more detailed explanation - but you can always ask a followup question.